# How to group multiple yaml fields into one

Tags: go, yaml

This is the data I have:

```
[alpha:0.1, beta:0.2] //1
[alpha:0.3, beta:0.4] //2
```

I am designing YAML for the data.

Note that

1. `alpha` and `beta` could be changed.
2. The length of `[alpha:0.1, beta:0.2]` can be increased and decreased. I want to group `alpha` and `beta` together.

I have read a few basic tutorial, but I do not know how to group `alpha` and `beta` together.

Here is my attempt:

```
params: 
  - 
    paramKey: alpha
    paramVal: 0.1
  - 
    paramKey: beta
    paramVal: 0.2
  - 
    paramKey: alpha
    paramVal: 0.3
  - 
    paramKey: beta
    paramVal: 0.4
```

Update:

I used the following:

```
params: 
  - alpha: 0.1
    beta: 0.2
  - alpha: 0.3
    beta: 0.4
```

Code:

```
func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    fByte, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    var m params
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(fByte, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", m)
}

type params struct {
    params []map[string]float32 `yaml:"params"`
}
```

The output is `{[]}`.

Comment: You need to use yaml not json.  See my additional answer below.

Comment: My bad. I have changed but the output is `{[]} `.

Comment: Just use yaml without `params:` and out-dented.  See my fixed answer below.

Comment: Export your fields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- alpha: 0.1
  beta: 0.2
- alpha: 0.3
  beta: 0.4
```

And here's some (tested) Go code to unmarshal into a slice of maps:

```
    var params []map[string]float64

    s := `---
- alpha: 0.1
  beta: 0.2
- alpha: 0.3
  beta: 0.4
`
    if err := yaml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s)).Decode(&params); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error decoding YAML:", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println(params)
```

Comment: `alpha` and `beta` can be changed anything else as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, I have tried `[]map[string]float64`, but I got `line 1: cannot unmarshal !!map into []map[string]float64`

Comment: Sorry @John Hass, I didn't really get what you meant by they could be changed.  I have adjusted the answer accordingly.
Remove the params: from the yaml.

Comment: They could be [`gamma: 0.5, omega: 0.6`]. Make sense?

Comment: Undeleted and upvoted.